# How to set the platform on a per test basis for jest tests?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, jestjs

I'm testing react-native components with jest and I often use things like this in my styles:

```
import { StyleSheet, Platform } from 'react-native';

export default StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    paddingTop: Platform.OS === 'ios' ? 30 : 10,
  }
});
```

The problem I'm having is that in the jest tests `Platform.OS` is always `'ios'` which means that the android branch doesn't get tested.

[This](https://github.com/facebook/jest/blob/master/packages/jest-react-native/jest-preset.json) lets me think that I could maybe change this through a jest config but since I don't want to change it globally but on a per test basis this doesn't make sense anyway.

Comment: Have you tried using variable environments ?

Comment: This issue seems to be more about files with platform-specific extensions than platform conditionals, but perhaps you could comment there with your problem: https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/1370.

Comment: Also, this is by no means a very elegant solution, but you might want to try the approach mentioned as part of https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/1738. Namely, just require `react-native` and directly assign a value to `Platform.OS` before running the test.

Answer (score 2):

Try adding this to the top of your test file.

```
jest.mock('Platform', () => {
    const Platform = require.requireActual('Platform');
    Platform.OS = 'android';
    return Platform;
});
const Platform = require('Platform');
```

You might need to make a different file for iOS, but which ever platform you set in the mock will work for your test spec file.

Comment: that's it! creating a different file for android in my case, testing only the variation for this platform solved my problem and coverage is 100% covered! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to mock out each platform using the `haste` property of your Jest preset. I'd recommend using [`jest-expo`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jest-expo) which extends the default React Native Jest preset and runs the tests multiple times, each with a different platform.

> disclaimer: I added this functionality to `jest-expo` when I encountered the same issue.